# Facebook ShareDialog - Doesn't shows up on sharePhotoContent

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-sdk-4.0

I have added all the content provider's in the AndroidManifest.xml.

ShareDialog with **ShareLinkContent** is working fine but while trying to upload the photo it isn't working. Nothing Happens, doesn't displays any dialog.

```
Uri uri1 = Uri.parse("file://" + path);
    Bitmap bitmap=null;

    try {
        bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), uri1);
    } catch (Exception e) {
      // TODO: handle exception
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    //bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher);

    SharePhoto photo = new SharePhoto.Builder()
            .setBitmap(bitmap)
            .build();

    ArrayList<SharePhoto> photos = new ArrayList<>();
    photos.add(photo);

    if (ShareDialog.canShow(SharePhotoContent.class)) {
        SharePhotoContent content = new SharePhotoContent.Builder()
                .setPhotos(photos)
                .setContentUrl(Uri.parse("http://www.bakarapp.com/app/"))
                .build();


        shareDialog.show(content);
    }
```

Comment: Can you please try the sample app in the sdk folder to see if the photo uploading work for you?

Comment: Taking look at that sample code only i wrote my code in order to simplify for my app.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**After reporting the bug to Facebook, I got their help in rectifying my code.**

The real problem seems to be that I was setting both a photo and a content URL, that doesn't make sense when sharing a photo. Just set the photo in the SharePhotoContent and the share dialog will be correctly shown

```
 if (ShareDialog.canShow(SharePhotoContent.class)) {
    SharePhotoContent content = new SharePhotoContent.Builder()
            .setPhotos(photos)
            .build();

    shareDialog.show(content);
}
```

Comment: in my case i cant get pass the if statement.  It doesnt allow to share Photo Content. is it happening with you?

Comment: @Araibkarim no in my case its working fine. exactly whats your issue? can you post your code as a new question.